# How to disable a <select> <option> on change/select of an item of another <select><option> using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have two `<select> <option>` like

```
 <select name="fm" id="fm" class="form-control" >
    <option value="01" >All</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<select name="fq" id="fq" class="form-control" ng-disabled="MonthVal">
   <option value="Q1">Q1</option>
   <option value="Q2">Q2</option>
   <option value="Q3">Q3</option>
   <option value="Q4">Q4</option>
</select>
```

I want to disable the `fm` totally on change/select of any item in `fq` and vice-versa using Angular Js 1.5

Comment: <select name="fm" id="fm" class="form-control" data-ng-model="fm" >

<select name="fq" id="fq" class="form-control" ng-disabled="fm">

Comment: @Raj thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just disable the `select`s by checking if the other select has a value selected. You can do that by using `ng-model`:

```
<select name="fm" id="fm" class="form-control"
        ng-model="fm"
        ng-disabled="fq">
    <!-- // -->
</select>

<select name="fq" id="fq" class="form-control"
        ng-model="fq"
        ng-disabled="fm">
    <!-- // -->
</select>
```